# In Django model, how to save DateTime for two different timezones at the same time when saving one field with auto_now_add = True option?

Tags: django, model

I have a Django model which has an auto current time saving DateTime field.
I want to add another DateTime field for another timezone which time difference with the previous DateTime field is exact time difference between two time zones.

This is how I have done. I think there should be better way to get it done.  It's Django, right?

```
class IcecreamManager(models.Manager):
    def create_icecream(self, name=None, qty=None):
        icecream = self.create(name=name, qty=qty)
        icecream.create_date_kr = icecream.create_date + datetime.timedelta(hours=9)
        icecream.save()
        return iceream

class Icecream(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    qty = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    create_date_kr = models.DateTimeField(null=True)

    objects = BuyFourManager()

>>> Icecream.objects.create_icecream(name='Vanila', qty=3)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try following solution by setting default parameter

```
import datetime
import pytz
class Icecream(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    qty = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    create_date_kr = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now+datetime.timedelta(hours=9))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I tested with your solution and it didn't work.

First, value for default should be something callable and your code was not callable. I think this is just a mistake.  
Second, two datetime fields will have values in different moments. `create_date_kr` is set when a model instance was created and `create_date` is set when the instance is saved for the first time in an actual table.  
I might have a wrong idea about how Django model works but this is how I  understand for now.

Comment: oh ya i understand. why not override save() for the purpose

Comment: Good point.  If I override save method, I can't set proper value for `create_date_kr` because value for `create_date` does not exist before finishing save process.  
You might have a different idea on this.